# How to implement the calculation fields of Mongodb template, and what good ideas do you have?

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

In template configuration, a calculation field needs to be added. The database is mongodb, and I don't know what good design solution is available

```
Calculated field=$Field1 * $Field2 + 233
```

How to convert this expression into mongodb syntax or use other methods to handle it (in fact, there may also be variables such as time and functions that will not be discussed for now).
The current idea is to save the template fields and add them to the configuration table, and use addFields to query the fields each time

---- supplement

Using C #, MongoDB. Driver driver implementation, specific requirements such as a product information template can be added with custom display fields for the product. For example, it has two custom fields: `price` field and `quantity`. Now, add a calculation field for the amount, specifying the formula as price * quantity. The template is set, and when I add product information, I can automatically calculate the amount based on the price and quantity

Comment: _"In template configuration, ..."_  Template configuration of what?  _"How to convert this expression ..."_  What _language/tool/etc._ uses that expression?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Added, please advise. Thank you

Comment: Do you mean something like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XppjA6IasQz "link to example -->")?

Comment: More complex, I want to convert mathematical expressions 1+2 * 3 into corresponding syntax, which involves sequence, etc 
{"$add":[1,{
"$multiply": [
          "$quantity",
          "$price"
        ]
      }]}

Comment: You will need to find/implement a grammar parser/generator. Here's an interesting article about parser generators.  https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-csharp/

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thank you. I found the idea I wanted: inverse Polish notation. I found an implementation of inverse Polish notation and modified it, ultimately achieving conversion

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the inverse Polish notation, one can achieve their desired requirements  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation